# Windows form sizing issue

Tags: vb.net, winforms, highdpi

I tbh don't know, I got 1 butto. To extend the form width or bring it to normal, on my laptop at 100% screen scale I get it to work, at 125% scale it gets almost to the edge, 150% scale it won't go a few pixels.

At 150% me.width turned to 1087 not the 1389 programmed. Also if it helps maximize and close buttons on top right disappear.

```
If txt.textlength = 4 then
    If me.width = 1026 = true then
        Me.width = 1389
    Elseif me.width = 1389 then
        Me.width =1026
    End if
End if
```

I'm stumped :/ ,

Comment: Your application needs to be DpiAware -- You have to specify the .NET version you're targeting

Comment: In app.manifest it's set to true,  .net 5.0

Comment: app.manifest is used to specify what version of Windows your app is supporting. You must uncomment at least Windows 10 -- The DpiAwareness mode is set in the Project's configuration file, main `<PropertyGroup>`. Add `<ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode>` -- You're targeting .NET, not .NET Framework

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 Automatic scaling and high DPI support are tough topics as the actual measures vary on specific projects. You shouldn't attempt to calculate the numbers as they can look pretty bad under a different setup.

Comment: Issue isn't associated with the dpi, the for frame isn't reaching correct sizes on the scale zoom. :|  losing the close button on the top of frame meaning it moved bit wont size the the form frame. Idk it's a weird glitch maybe b.c I'm playing with form size after it's already running?  :/